# Is Git Command line (git bash) same for all services which is github and gitlab or is there any difference in commands?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Is Git Command line (git bash) same for all services which is github and gitlab or is there any difference in git commands ?

I am beginner in this git world. Please help ?

Comment: Git bash has little to do with services. In fact stop using git bash and start using the unix subsystem which can be natively installed on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git commands are the same on all services. Services like Github or Gitlab are the place where you push the code to (the git remote). Whereas Git is the version control system that manages the codebase and changes.

TLDR: Same commands.

Answer (score 2):

Git is separate from both of the services you mention. Git is a version control system, and both Github and GitLab are just hosting the repositories you create with Git.

Git commands, and Git in general will be the same no matter what repository hosting service you choose to use. You can entirely use Git without using either Github, Gitlab, or any other service. It is completely independent.

Answer (score 0):

> **Git is a Version Control System**

Version control is a system that **records changes to a file or set of files** over time so that you can **recall specific versions later**.

It allows you to revert selected files back to a previous state, revert the entire project back to a previous state, compare changes over time, see who last modified something that might be causing a problem, who introduced an issue and when, and more. Using a VCS also generally means that if you screw things up or lose files, you can easily recover. In addition, you get all this for very little overhead.

> **Github and Gitlab are some sites that provide Git hosting.**

Basically these are **storage in cloud** where you can push your code so that it can be managed across various developers, teams.

---

Thus **commands depend on VCS you use** like Git, Mercurial, SVN etc. and have no dependency on hosting platform you use like Github, Bigbucket, Gitlab etc .

---

Thus for **Git commands are same** for Gitlab, Github or Bigbucket etc.

Answer (score 0):

Git is a distributed version control system. Git maintains metadata (a tree structure) with your source code in its special directory `.git`. So, when you run commands like:

```
git log
```

It returns the list of commits in chronological order with the commit message and the author information. Similar to this, if you run any other command like

```
git commit
git rebase <branch name>
git merge <branch name>
```

All of these commands are using the bare metal  "git". It has nothing to do with GitHub or GitLab or any other vendor. Now, if you want your code to be reviewed by your colleague, then use a Pull Request in GitHub or Merge Request in GitLab.  In that case, you are using GitHub/GitLab feature rather than Git system. Now, these vendors use Git as an underlying backend structure and store the repositories in their `bare` format usually on the server-side.

Now, let say you want to use the Issue List, GitLab CI/CD, Auto DevOps, Groups, Deploy Key, Namespaces, etc. then you are GitLab or similar GitHub features but not Git.

So, to answer your question, mostly what you do on bash with git commands is git only, but these vendors provide a lot of things which are not git.